# Screencast and training tags on Stack Overflow and Programmers

Tags: support, tags, asking-questions, closed-questions, close-reasons

What type of questions should be asked under the following two tags to avoid closing?

This is the description of `training` tag on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/about). [Stack Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow) has no description at all.

> You may use this tag when your question revolves around for example:
>   Where can I find materials to train for ... ? Asking which training
>   course is best for you is off topic or not constructive at best as the
>   answers will be equally valid and only apply to you.

The definition of the tag is quite vague and even questions that don't ask for the best course are closed and deleted. The question that asks for a *training* or *screencast* of certain type is sometimes closed and sometimes not.

This vagueness is abused by some users who don't even read the question and quickly close good questions under these tags. I have seen downvoting a question within a few seconds and closing during five minutes. This is the reason, the tags should have better description to warn the askers not to waste their time.

EDIT: I picked up one example showing a contrast

1. *[Good WCF + JSON + JSONP screencast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240717)*: correct question
2. *[Do records showing the daily work of programmers exist?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/145645/do-records-showing-the-daily-work-of-programmers-exist)*: incorrect question. Asked on *Stack Overflow*, it was downvoted in a few seconds, closed in five minutes, and deleted in a few hours. It was asked again on *Programmers* with positive interest, but it was closed in a few hours as well.

Comment: Care to post examples of good-on-topic questions that are correctly tagged `training` on SO, and are closed? I'm sure they exist, and it'd be good to reference them here.

Answer (score 1):

Tagging a question with particular tags should in no way affect whether they're closed. Use a tag if it's appropriate (and improve the tag's wiki if that appropriateness is not clear). Vote to close a question if the question's content is not appropriate on its site.

The [training](/questions/tagged/training) tag, in general, should not be used on Stack Overflow. It's most often applied to questions like *Should I take Random Certification Training XYZ*, which is considered [off](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128562#128562)-[topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128556#128556). I've seen good, on-topic questions asked using this tag, but they're the exception, not the rule. From a quick search, I see a lot of neural network training questions that use this tag - I think those would be better served with the [neural-network](/questions/tagged/neural-network) or [neural-network-tuning](/questions/tagged/neural-network-tuning) tags. I would support modifying the tag wikis as needed - go for it!

**EDIT:** Looks like you're referring to your most recent question, [Records of daily work of programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281472/records-of-daily-work-of-programmers), which was closed a few hours ago. Sorry to say, but that's not considered an on-topic question on Stack Overflow, no matter the tags. See [What Stack Overflow is Not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not), and in particular [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128562#128562) answer, and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128561#128561) one.

Comment: I wasn't referring to this my question, but it was deleted on `stackoverflow` sooner than in 2 days period though on `programmers` [it was](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/145645/records-of-daily-work-of-programmers) very positively valued by it's members before it was closed for unknown reasons.

Comment: Not sure what your point is, @xralf. Stack Overflow and Programmers have different mandates. Your question was off-topic on SO, but on-topic on Programmers.

Comment: *...but it was closed on Programmers*. You should ask that over on the Programmers meta.

Comment: It was closed on StackOverflow (the one you're linking) during 5 minutes and downvoted during a few seconds after asking and now it's deleted (after few hours). Though, this question is not about it. It's about the descriptions of tags `training` and `screencast` to avoid closing questions that are in scope of the definition.

Comment: And I think that's the rub, @xralf. I can't speak for Programmers, but there are very few questions about training that would be on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Then the tags should be better defined. I'm subscribed to these tags RSS channels and it's so often deleted and wasting the askers time, so the users should know what is allowed here.

Comment: And like I said, @xralf, go for it. You can edit tag wikis (which would need to be approved by two high-rep users).

Comment: No problem, but first I'd like to know what community things about it and should be written there to be compatible with the rules.